# How does an absolute value operator interact with partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, absolute-value

I wish to take the partial derivative with respect to $y$ of the following expression:

$$g(x,y)=\log{\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\right|}$$

where $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is some function which depends on $x$ and $y$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x$. How does the absolute value operator $|\cdot|$ interact with the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ if I want to evaluate $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y)$?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or references on how to address such situations, also in more general cases.

Comment: How much do you know about $f$? Is it continuous? Differentiable? It may be that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ exists everywhere but $f$ is not continuous. If so, is it always non-zero?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that $f(x,y)$ is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: @J.Galt: what if $f(x,y)=1$ everywhere? Then $g$ is not defined.

Comment: @mrsamy: For the purpose of this question, you can assume that $f$ is also continuous, differentiable, and not constant. =) I'm not looking for special cases, but for the general rule behind it.

Comment: @J.Galt: My point is that that assumption is not sufficient either. Consider the case when $f(x,y)=y^2+4y+e^y$. the function $g$ is still not defined:-)

Comment: I wrote an answer below. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y)\ne 0$ everywhere, by the chain rule, you need the existence of partial derivative with respect to $y$ for the map
$$
y\mapsto |\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y)|
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$g(x,y)=\log|f_x|.$$ Then you have that $$g_y=\frac{1}{|f_x|}\frac{f_x}{|f_x|}f_{xy}=\frac{f_{xy}}{f_x}.$$